# flutter: Another exception was thrown: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I tried to save some value in shared preference and retrieve it whenever I need it but when i call the

```
String username = SharedPrefUtils.readPrefStr('name');
```

it dosent get value to the string and getting the error

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

  class SharedPrefUtils {

   static saveStr(String key, String message) async {
     final SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   pref.setString(key, message);
}

static readPrefStr(String key) async {
    final SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return pref.getString(key);
}

}
```

saving value

```
 SharedPrefUtils.saveStr("name", _username);
```

but I am getting this error!

```
flutter: Another exception was thrown: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

Comment: `readPrefStr()` is a Future so you'll need to `await` it

Answer (score 1):

You have to typecast. This Might work.

```
 Future<String> readPrefStr() async {
   final SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String value= pref.getString(key);
    return value;
  }
```

Comment: this is still unusable with TextField textcontroller class as initial value